# TFS is not formatting line break correctly in Markdown table

Tags: tfs, markdown

I have a markdown file that I'm hosting in TFS with a table and I'm trying to add line breaks using `<br>`.

In Visual Studio code preview, everything is formatted correctly but in the browser, the line breaks are showing up as `<br>`.

How do I get this to work properly?

Here is my markdown code:

```
|Component |Details|
|------|------|
|Values|This is Line 1 <br><br>This is Line 2<br><br>This is Line 3<br>This is Line 4<br>This is Line 5<br>This is Line 6<br>|
```

This is what I want my output to look like/what it looks like in VS Code:

[image]

This is what it looks like in TFS:

[image]

How can I fix the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a granular feature breakdown between TFS and Azure DevOps, but [they should be similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops). In Azure DevOps [this will only work in wikis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#supported-in-markdown-widget--pull-requests--readme-files--wikis):

> To start a new line, use the HTML break tag (`<br/>`) (Works within a Wiki but not elsewhere)